# Replace all "(" and ")" in a string in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, replaceall

How to replace all "(" and ")" in a string with a fullstop, in Java? I tried in the following way:

```
String url = "https://bitbucket.org/neeraj_r/url-shortner)";
url.replaceAll(")", ".");
url.replaceAll(")", ".");
```

But it does not work. The error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unmatched closing
')'
 )
at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.String.replaceAll(Unknown Source)
at com.azzist.cvConversion.server.URLChecker.main(URLChecker.java:32)
```

I think this problem will be there in all regex too. Adding `\` before `)` did not work.

Comment: add \\  not \ .  you need to add two double slashes

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use replaceAll in one go:

```
url.replaceAll("[()]", ".")
```

Explanation:

- `[()]` matches both `(` and `)`, the brackets don't need to be escaped inside the `[]` group.

EDIT (as pointed out by @Keppil):

Note also, the String `url` is not changed by the replace, it merely returns a new String with the replacements, so you'd have to do:

```
url = url.replaceAll("[()]", ".");
```

Answer (score 15):

You need to escape `'('` and `')'` with `"\\("` and `"\\)"` respectively:

```
url = url.replaceAll("\\)", ".");  
url = url.replaceAll("\\(", ".")
```

Comment: There is a small mistake in your answer. You are only replacing ")". But also this will not work. Your logic will not work for "(". url = url.replaceAll("\\(", "."); will not replace "("

Comment: It works using java 1.8+.  Need to add 2 back slashes \\ in front of ( and ). url = url.replaceAll("\\\)", ".");  is good

Answer (score 8):

[`replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) expects a `regex` as first parameter, and parantheses have special meaning there.

use [`replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) instead:

```
String url = "https://bitbucket.org/neeraj_r/url-shortner)";
url = url.replace("(", ".").replace(")", ".");
```

Note that the `url =` part is important to save the result of the replacement. Since `String`s are *immutable*, the original `String` isn't changed, but a new one is created. To keep the result `url` needs to point to this one instead.

Comment: Both 'url.replace("(",".") and url.replaceAll("\\(",".") work fine. The point here is "url = url.replace(...)". In the question the "url = ..." was missing. Thus the string will be replaced but not written somewhere.

Comment: @emempe: Yes, that was important too, but the error in OPs example was due to a regex error. I'll add a note about the `url =` part too.

Comment: @Keppil I want to convert all the "(" in the String. By using .replace, I think I can convert only the first occurrence.

Comment: @Neeraj: No, `replace()` takes care of all of them.

Answer (score 2):

1. String is immutable.
2. `)` should be escaped with 2 backslashes.

So the code would look like this:

```
String url = "https://bitbucket.org/neeraj_r/url-shortner)";
// is you need to escape all of them, use "[()]" pattern, instead of "\\)"
String s = url.replaceAll("\\)", "."); 
System.out.println(url);
System.out.println(s);
```

And the output:

```
https://bitbucket.org/neeraj_r/url-shortner)
https://bitbucket.org/neeraj_r/url-shortner.
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding a single `\` will not work, because that will try to evaluate `\)` as an escaped special character which it isn't.

You'll need to use "\)". The first `\` escapes the second, producing a "normal" `\`, which in turn escapes the `)`, producing a regex matching exactly a closing paranthesis `)`.

The general purpose solution is to use [`Pattern.quote`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29), which takes an arbitrary string and returns a regex that matches exactly that string.

Answer (score 1):

You also could use org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.replace(String, String, String) which doesn't use regex

From apache commons library http://commons.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

Method `String#replaceAll` expects a regular expression and `(` as well as `)` are special characters (marking the group) so you need to escape them to be non-special `url.replaceAll("\\)", ".");`.

Also you can replace both character at once with pattern `url.replaceAll("[()]", ".");`. You can see that in this context the brackets are not escaped. That is because of regEx context - inside of `[]` they don't have any special meaning.

Look at [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Because `)` is character of regex, so you need to escape it. Try this:

```
url.replaceAll("\)", "\.");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
url.replaceAll("\\)", ".").replaceAll("\\(", ".");;
```